# Estimates of certain exponential series

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I am interested in series of the form

$$S(k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-an^\alpha},$$ where $a>0$ and $0<\alpha\leq1$ are fixed parameters. Clearly, this series converges, i.e. $S(k)\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$. My questions are: Is some special function representation of $S$ known? And: Do there exist useful bounds, e.g. $S(k) \leq c\,e^{-a'k^\alpha}$ for all integers $k$, for suitable $c,a'>0$?

Comment: I'm wondering, are you looking for an equivalent when k--> ∞ ?

Or you just want an estimate of S, the infinite sum?

 What you might study is the function define with the "a" parameter. For instance it is derivable as many time as you like, maybe you can make approximation regarding S', S".

Comment: I now saw that one can estimate like $$S(k)\leq\int_k^\infty dn\,e^{-a(n-1)^\alpha}$$ which leads to incomplete Gamma functions, that is good enough for me.